# IBM Cloud docker dind service not working in VPC cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, vpc

When I start the hyper ledger network on a free Kubernetes classic cluster of IBM Cloud following the GitHub link https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes.git, the chain code instantiates.

But when I try to instantiate the chain code in IBM's VPC cluster, I am getting **Post http://docker:2375/containers/create? i/o timeout**

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you give me the output of `kubectl version --short`?

Comment: Client Version: v1.19.4
Server Version: v1.18.12+IKS

Comment: Do you have a public gateway attached to this VPC?

Comment: yes, public gateway is attached.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Modify the Kubernetes configuration scripts
>
> If there is any change in network topology, need to modify the configuration files (.yaml files) appropriately. The configuration files are located in artifacts and configFiles directory. For example, if you decide to increase/decrease the capacity of persistent volume then you need to modify createVolume.yaml. 
> The Kubernetes Server version v1.11.x or above uses containerd as its container runtime therefore using docker.sock of the worker node is not possible. You need to deploy and use a Docker daemon in a container. In case, your Kubernetes server version is smaller than 1.11.x then you need to modify the configFiles/peersDeployment.yaml file to point to a Docker service. Change instances of tcp://docker:2375 to unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock with a text editor.

It seems that the `tcp://docker:2375`  to `unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock` value needs to be changed. Please refer to the github link you gave me for details.

[blockchain-network-on-kubernetes](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes)

Comment: Thanks @myeongkii kim for the reply. Because our kubernetes version is >1.11.x. We are using the docker dind service tcp://docker:2375. This service is not working in VPC cluster.